# NetBeans - highlight  html syntax with twig files

Tags: netbeans, symfony, netbeans-7, netbeans-plugins

I am having trouble figuring out how to highlight my html syntax in `NetBeans IDE 7.1.1` when I open file having `twig` extension.

I tried to install the `php symfony framework plugin` for NetBeans but nothing changed.

Comment: There is a "Twig for Netbeans" extension. Can you check if it is installed/activated using the Tools => Plugins => Installed view?

Comment: Thats strange. Did you try to install the following plugin: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/37069/php-twig

Comment: This Twig plugin is not available for Netbeans 7.1.x

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to install any plugin.

You need just to add a new file extension `twig` in

> NetBeans → Miscellaneous → Options → Files

And then you need to associate the `twig` extension to `HTML`.

The result will be the following:

[image: Coloured code screenshot]

Comment: Hmmm.  Have you actually tried this?  Twig is not html and I rather doubt that you will get useful twig oriented high lighting from a html processor.

Comment: Yes, I tried. so you can see the HTML part with the right color. Just the twig part will be in black. You can see the result on the pic I attached.

Comment: still better than nowt

Answer (score 1):

Closest thing you can do is adding `twig` extension in `Tools->Options->Miscellaneous->Files` tab and set MIME as `TPL (text/x-tpl)`. By doing this editor will not show html errors.

Answer (score 1):

There is this Plugin for NetBeans 7.0 (and above) which I just found, installed and it is working fine in my NetBeans 7.2.1.

PHP Twig Plugin:
     http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/37069/php-twig

Install:
0. Download the Plugin.
1. Menu > Tools > Plugins > Downloaded [find it and install it]
2. Activate it. Menu > Tools > Plugins > Installed [check and click Activate]
3. Restart NetBeans. (Close and Open again)
4. Enjoy it ;)